# Selenium and xpath: Clicking a checkbox in one table's column, based on text in another?

Tags: xpath, selenium

Basically there is a table with names, edit buttons, and a checkbox at the end column that I want to check on with selenium. But I want to make sure I click on the one I created with selenium and that's where my problems begin.

Using the selenium IDE, the names xpath is

```
//tr[5]/td[2]
```

The checkbox is

```
//tr[5]/td[4]/input
```

So the text is in column 2 and the box is column 4, and my record would be the 5th one. but I cannot for the life of me get ANY text search to work. Even something basic like

```
<tr>
<td>storeText</td>
<td>//tr[contains(text(), 'McGowan')]/td[2]</td>
<td>text</td>
</tr>
```

Even if the text matches identically, it gives me the locator not found error. No matter what combination i use to find xpath by text it has never worked, and ive spent quite a few hours reading every combination out there.

We are using the IDE and the RC in html, so no java or any other exporting.

Thank! (My first post!)

Answer (score 2):

```
//td[text()='McGowan']/../td/input[@type='checkbox']
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: scary thing is, i clicked on a random link on the right side suggestions and found one i never saw before
//tr[contains(., 'text')]/td[3]/a
and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This might be odd, but the coment below the answer, regarding a random click that let to the answer ---> //tr[contains(., 'text')]/td[3]/a <--- was just randomly verified as exactly what I needed.

Good job guys.